# Apply function to any two elements of a list - Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a function which calculates the jaccard index for two parse strings. The function is working OK and its code is below:

```
def jack(a,b):
    x=a.split()
    y=b.split()
    k=float(len(list(set(x)&set(y))))/float(len(list(set(x) | set(y))))
    return k
```

However, when I want to apply the function for any two elements of a list, an error appears. My list is called "a" and it's like this :[ ["Coca Cola"],["Coca Sc"]]. The error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-0d7031267380> in <module>()
----> 1 jack(a[2],a[3])

<ipython-input-27-256123b04a44> in jack(a, b)
      1 def jack(a,b):
----> 2     x=a.split()
      3     y=b.split()
      4     k=float(len(list(set(x)&set(y))))/float(len(list(set(x) | set(y))))
      5     return k

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I know it´s because a[2] is a list too, but I would like to find a way to deal with this to have the expected output. Maybe I can modify my function or the way I enter the output.

Comment: Why not just index the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "for any two elements of a list"? Can you explain the new behavior's desired differences from the old behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have one element lists and you are passing the lists as the parameters whereas your function expects strings, I would recommend you to invoke your function like this

```
jack(a[2][0], a[3][0])
```

Also, you dont have to convert the `set` to a `list` to find the length.

```
return float(len(set(x) & set(y))) / float(len(set(x) | set(y)))
```

should be enough here.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your variable `a` is a nested list. You should either flatten `a` or pass the arguments as:

`jack(a[2][0],a[3][0])`

#### Or, you could flatten your list as:

`a = [i[0] for i in a]`

then you can easily do:

`jack(a[0],a[1])`